# Simple Serial-to Wifi communication

Tags: serial, wifi

I'm working on controlling an incubator by writing commands to its serial port, a 9 pin RS232.  The commands are simple byte strings, such as #02ts.  The incubator responses are similar to the commands I send.  If I connect it to my computer with an RS232 to USB cable, everything works great.

Now I'm looking to control it remotely, and I was told to try a serial to wifi adapter.  I've come across a vast variety of items which claim to do this, and I'm lost when it comes to what each item is suited for, and I have no idea what exactly it is I need.  What is the best way to wirelessly communicate to this incubator's serial port?

Comment: You are better off with something dedicated as a wireless to serial module.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `ESP8266` based modules. They are very cheap and functional. And doing exactly what you need.

[Lots of relevant links here](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=esp8266&biw=1097&bih=590&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=bebCVPWvHoTZmAWdsoCQCQ&sqi=2&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ)

And [just a text search](https://www.google.co.nz/?gws_rd=ssl#q=esp8266) produces a useful amount.